# Calculate the mutual information value of 3D image

Tags: python

I would like to ask, how to use Python to calculate the mutual information value and standardized mutual information value of two three-dimensional images? Any help would be appreciated.
I have tried to use the function in sklearn to calculate the mutual information value a, but I found that when the mutual information is calculated again after rotating or translating the image, the value B is obtained. The difference between a and B is very small, so I personally think this method is not applicable to images. Am I right?Here's the code I used with the sklearn package.

```
def NMI(img1,img2):
    img1_ = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(img1)
    img2_ = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(img2)
    img2_ = np.reshape(img2_, -1)
    img1_ = np.reshape(img1_, -1)
    normalized_mutual_infor = mr.normalized_mutual_info_score(img1_, img2_)
    nmi = normalized_mutual_infor 
    print(nmi)

fixed_image = sitk.ReadImage(r"D:\Lung CT\RIDER Lung CT\001_1.mha", sitk.sitkFloat32)
moving_image = sitk.ReadImage(r"D:\Lung CT\RIDER Lung CT\001_2.mha", sitk.sitkFloat32)
tfm1 = sitk.ReadTransform(r'D:\6freedom\1_text2.tfm')
x = tfm1.GetParameters()[3]
y = tfm1.GetParameters()[4]
z = tfm1.GetParameters()[5]

transform1 = sitk.Euler3DTransform(tfm1)
transform1.SetParameters((0, 0, 0, x, y, z))
resample = sitk.Resample(moving_image, fixed_image, transform1, sitk.sitkLinear, 0.0, moving_image.GetPixelID())
NMI(fixed_image, resample)
#When the parameter is (0,0,0, x, y, z), the result is 0.524628297588729
#When the parameter is (1,0,0, x, y, z), the result is 0.4657578384754303
#The unit of rotation is radians, so the image has been rotated a lot, 
#but the difference between the two results is very small.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a good question. SO is not a place where you ask for code without efforts. Show us what you tried, show us your research.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have tried to use the function in sklearn to calculate the mutual information value a, but I found that when the mutual information is calculated again after rotating or translating the image, the value B is obtained. The difference between a and B is very small, so I personally think this method is not applicable to images. Am I right?

Comment: Please, edit your post by showing your code and results, so we can build on it. Follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to provide a minimal reproductible example.

Comment: I have modified my post.

Answer (score 2):

From this nice [notebook](https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/mutual_information.html), it seems one can use the joint histogram of the input images e.g.

```
import numpy as np
def mutual_information(hgram):
     # Mutual information for joint histogram
     # Convert bins counts to probability values
     pxy = hgram / float(np.sum(hgram))
     px = np.sum(pxy, axis=1) # marginal for x over y
     py = np.sum(pxy, axis=0) # marginal for y over x
     px_py = px[:, None] * py[None, :] # Broadcast to multiply marginals
     # Now we can do the calculation using the pxy, px_py 2D arrays
     nzs = pxy > 0 # Only non-zero pxy values contribute to the sum
     return np.sum(pxy[nzs] * np.log(pxy[nzs] / px_py[nzs]))
hist_2d, x_edges, y_edges = np.histogram2d(img1.ravel(),img2.ravel(),bins=20)
mi = mutual_information(hist_2d)
print(mi)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
After reading the code and links you provided, I have the following two questions, and I hope you can answer them if you can: (1) Why take the value of bins in the code as 20? (2) It is calculated in the code is a 2D image, but my image is 3D. How to calculate it?

Comment: @tang It does not matter that your image is 3D. The `ravel` function will flatten any ND-array. The reason a 2D histogram is used is because you are computing the occurrence of pixel amplitudes in TWO images. Basically, in this implementation, each ND image is reduced to a 1D distribution, and the 1D distributions are used to build a joint (2D) histogram.

Comment: Somehow, I forgot to answer this. Sirgogo comment is correct the number of histogram dimensions is related to the number of images e.g. if you are using 3 images you may need 3D histogram. The number of bins is a parameter that you change based on the problem, you can play with the code and check its effect for different images. Usually, the number of bins is based on the number of colors e.g. large when you have many colors and small when you have small number. You may also use this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/798/calculating-optimal-number-of-bins-in-a-histogram).